# Reliable method of uploading extensive trees of sub-folders to remote ftp server with a single interaction?

Tags: nautilus, ftp, filezilla, caja

I would like to be able to initiate uploading and then go and have lunch.

I do not have permission to install software on the remote server. The ftp service is the only one available.

Using ftp from a terminal window is not convenient because it cannot recursively load sub-folders.

I use Caja 1.12.7 (on Ubuntu Mate). I tried uploading a folder containing two sub-folders and about 37 files spread among them, totalling 300 kBytes. It failed on two files with the message

> The file is not a directory.

(I wonder whether Caja fails (but not on every occasion) when copying the first file to a new sub-folder it has/should have just created.)

Soon I will want, for example, to upload a WordPress installation which has hundreds of sub-folders, thousands of files and millions of bytes.
I am hoping to upload all the files with one command/action, so having to cope with potentially hundreds of fails by Caja would not be convenient.

Of course, the problem could be with my local setup or the remote server setup.

Further information:

- I tried Firefox but their add-on for ftp has been withdrawn.
- I tried Nautilus but my test case failed on one file in the same way.

Comment: Try ftp:// in e.g. Firefox instead of (Ubuntu Mate?) Caja.

Comment: @Hannu Would that require a Firefox add-on?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded FileZilla 3.15.0.2 from the Ubuntu Mate Welcome screen.

It worked fine on my test case. I also tried it with the wp-includes folder of a Wordpress installation. This is ~17Mbytes in 896 items, with sub-folders nested up to 5 deep. I copied it to the remote server and back again.

The number of items was correct.

I think I will go with FileZilla.

(N.B. The total bytes in the recopied folder were 16,978,859 instead of the original 16,982,310, but I imagine that was an artifact of the way they were stored. I looked for differences between the folders and got

```
$ diff -rq wp-includes/ ../wp-includes/
Files wp-includes/images/crystal/license.txt and ../wp-includes/images/crystal/license.txt differ
Files wp-includes/js/codemirror/csslint.js and ../wp-includes/js/codemirror/csslint.js differ
```

but ignoring white space on the pairs of files with `diff -w` gave the result that they are seen as the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox AddOns:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=ftp&platform=Linux&appver=83.0&utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_content=addons-manager-search

*note, I have not tried any of these personally*

Please read comments below; this route doesn't seem to be very worthwhile.

Comment: Alas, it's not there any more: "The Firefox platform development team recently announced plans to first disable, and then remove the implementation for built-in FTP from the browser."  https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2020/04/13/what-to-expect-for-the-upcoming-deprecation-of-ftp-in-firefox/

Comment: Right. There still seems to be at least one another you can try. I have no idea if it works for your tasks though.

Comment: I had a look at the other Firefox search results. The one that suggests it implements ftp gets some very bad reviews. I think I'll drop the Firefox route.

Comment: Right - I'll let this remain here - if not for anything else than as a warning for others.